# Get queryset of related objects of field from queryset

Tags: python, django

for example, i have two models.

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Book(models.Model):
    store = models.ForiengKey(Store, on_delete=....)
```

I have one queryset of Store objs. I need a queryset of related books with this objs queryset.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

get an instance of the Store object

```
store_1 = Store.objects.first()
```

get books associated in that store object by

```
books = store_1.book_set.all()
```

if you have a related name

```
store = models.ForiengKey(Store, related_name='mystore')
```

then you can call this way

```
books = store_1.mystore.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access it like this:

```
store_object.book_set.all()
```

another way is using `related_name` for convenient in your model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    store = models.ForiengKey(Store, related_name='books', on_delete=....)
```

and select it like this:

```
store_object.books.all()
```